# XSLT Getting attribute from root node in template

Tags: xslt, sitemap

how can I get a "locale" attribute from urlset tag inside in template, tried many variants but nothing works from it...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="https://kazik.reved-rfs.ru/sitemap.xsl"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" locale="hu-hu">
```

```
<xsl:template match="sitemap:urlset">
    ...
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="urlset/@locale"/>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the template for `sitemap:urlset` if you use an XPath like `urlset/@locale` it will be looking for a `urlset` element that is a child of the `sitemap:urlset` element, and then looking for the `@locale` on that element.

In order to address the `@locale` element for the matched `sitemap:urlset` element, use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@locale"/>
```

You could also use an explicit XPath that "jumps up" to the top of the tree and selects from that element (but since you are already "standing on" that matched element, I'd use the relative XPath above):

```
<xsl:value-of select="/sitemap:urlset/@locale"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, second variant works :) But not first

Comment: @Reved The first variant works too - provided you are still in the context of the root `urlset` element, as indicated in your question: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MP42MN   Next time, please post a [mcve].